# Множество публичных ключей на 1 закрытый ключ

Tags: шифрование, rsa

Вопрос в следующем. Существуют ли способы получения нескольких открытых ключей из одного закрытого ключа? Я знаю что после генерации секретного ключа получу 1 публичный ключ, и сколько бы раз я не перегенерировал этот публичный ключ, он будет одинаковый. Слышал об широковещательном шифровании. Но не уверен подходит мне это или нет. Может быть есть какие то алгоритмы, которые позволяют реализовать то что мне нужно?